# How to get jpeg buffer from uploaded file on node red

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, jpeg, node-red, watson

I'm trying to create a webpage where users can upload a jpeg file from whatever device and then using the ibm watson image recognition get the results from that image.

I'm using node red in bluemix.

Here is a code i found on GitHub in which im basing my webpage but i can't figure out how to extract the file from the POST http multi part.

https://github.com/padiller/trafico

Thanks!

Comment: You need to import that code to node red to see all the nodes that im using.

Comment: This type of question is off topic for stackoverflow.  You could try extracting the shortest code necessary to the question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic